# How do I prove L'Hôpital's rule variation for complex functions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I need to prove the following version of L'Hôpital's rule for complex functions:

Let $f$ and $g$ be analytical at $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)=g(z_0)=0$ and $g$  is not identically zero: so the following limits exist $($whether $\infty$ or finite$)$ and equal:
$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$ .

I looked up online and found people using it but not a proof. I've found this, which I'm not sure why doesn't work here:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} =\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}\cdot\frac{z-z_{0}}{g(z)-g(z_{0})}
 =\frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$$

My guess it's something with power series.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $z_0$ is a simple zero of both $f$ and $g$. Then, if$$f(z)=a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots\text{ and }g(z)=b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots,$$we have\begin{align}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}\\&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{a_1+a_2(z-z_0)+\cdots}{b_1+b_2(z-z_0)+\cdots}\\&=\frac{a_1}{b_1}\\&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}.\end{align}Can you do the general case now?

Comment: Forgive me but I'm going to need a little bit of elaboration.
All I know for $f$ and $g$ is that $z_0$ is their zero of *some* value, and maybe even different values. 
Why do you assume that they both have a simple zero? and could you please explain where is your usage of it? I'm not fluent in zeros and poles.
Lastly, what do you mean by the "general case"?
Thanks again and sorry.

Comment: I proved the statmens assuming explicitely that $z_0$ is a simple zero of both $f$ and $g$. The general case is when there is som $n\in\mathbb N$ such that$$f(z)=a_n(z-z_0)^n+a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}+\cdots$$and there is a $m\in\mathbb N$ such that$$g(z)=b_m(z-z_0)^m+b_{m+1}(z-z_0)^{m+1}+\cdots$$but you can deal with it the same way that I dealt with the case in which $n=m=1$.

Comment: I now understand what you mean about the zeros, but why can you expand $f$ and $g$ into power series if they're only analytical at $z_0$? Is it Taylor series or Laurent series?
Thanks again

Comment: It's the Taylor series. If it didn't exist or if it didn't converge to $f(z)$ and to $g(z)$ near $z_0$, then $f$ and $g$ would no be analytic there.

Comment: how are we proving that the limit of $\frac{f}{g}$ exists either finite or $\inf$ ?

Comment: @R_Squared The proof is in my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos is it what IJM98 write in his answer?

Comment: @R_Squared I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but trying to do this same exercise and finding this post, I noticed some problems with the setting of the problem and the other answer given. I do this for anybody that stumbles onto the same exercise and can find this useful, and also this was the same as I would had wanted to find when I was searching for some help with the case where $g'(a)=0$.

---

So the thing is that the function $g$ should have the property that $g'(a)\neq 0$, so that the limit $\underset{z\to a}{lim} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$ can exist in general, in the set $\mathbb{C}$ meaning it is finite.

---

In the case of the "general case" that it is mentioned in the other answer, there is the following proposition from complex analysis:

> Let $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$, $R>0$ and $f,g\in\mathcal{H}(D(z_0,R))$ (holomorphic functions on the disc with center $z_0$ and radius $R$).If $z_0$ is a zero of order $k$ of $f$ and of order $l$ of $g$, then $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $h=f/g$ that is:
> · removable if $k\geq l$
> · a pole of order $l-k$ if $k<l$

We say that $z_0$ is a zero of order $k$ of $g$ if $0=g(z_0)=\cdots =g^{(k-1)}(z_0)$, but $g^{(k)}(z_0)\neq 0$.
So if $g'(a)=0$ (zero of order at least 2) then because of this proposition we will have that $f/g$ has a pole in $a$, so then $$\lim_{z\to a} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\infty$$
I can provide proofs for the mentioned proposition and the fact that $a$ is a pole (we don't care about the order) of $f$ $\iff$ $\underset{z\to a}{lim}f(z)=\infty$.